# WCF web service returning 404 over HTTPS but works over HTTP

Tags: .net, wcf, https

I've got a web service written years ago that works fine over http. It works via a web browser to see the service description and it responds correctly to soap calls. We now want to move it over to https.

I've made some changes to the web.config file to try and enable it to work over https. I can now call it via https in a browser and see the service description but I cannot call the web service using a soap call via https - I get a 404 error.

I am testing the soap calls by using Postman, so this seems to indicate the issue is either with the web.config or IIS.

I've found many posts with issues relating to WCF over https but as yet have not been successful at resolving this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Service related code from web.config shown below.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
  <service name="EComAPI" behaviorConfiguration="WCFAuthBehavior">
    <endpoint address="soap" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="IEComAPI" bindingConfiguration="httpbinding1"></endpoint>
    <endpoint address="soap" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="IEComAPI" bindingConfiguration="httpsbinding1"></endpoint>
    <endpoint address="rest" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IEComAPI" behaviorConfiguration="rest" bindingConfiguration="httpbinding2"></endpoint>
    <endpoint address="rest" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IEComAPI" behaviorConfiguration="rest" bindingConfiguration="httpsbinding2"></endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
  </service>
</services>

    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="httpbinding1">
          <security mode="None"></security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="httpsbinding1">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>

      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="httpbinding2">
          <security mode="None">
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="httpsbinding2">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WCFAuthBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="false" httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="rest">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

In summary:

- http web request to this service - ok
- http soap request to this service - ok
- https web request to this service - ok
- https soap request to this service - gives a 404

Answer (score 0):

If we want to call the service with SOAP style over HTTPS, we should use Wshttpbinding to publish the service endpoint and specify the client credential type(default value is windows).

```
    <system.serviceModel>
      <services>
        <service name="VM1.MyService" behaviorConfiguration="mybehavior">
          <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="VM1.IService" bindingConfiguration="mybinding"></endpoint>
          <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
        </service>
      </services>
      <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
          <binding name="mybinding">
            <security mode="Transport">
              <transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>
            </security>
          </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
      </bindings>
      <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
          <behavior name="mybehavior">
            <serviceMetadata />
          </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
      </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Then specify an https endpoint in IIS site binding module.
If we want to publish the service with Restful style, we should use WebHttpBinding.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/wcf-web-http-programming-model
At last, I have made a similar configuration which supports both SOAP style and Restful style(required that add the webget/webinvoke to operation method), and it support both https and http.

```
<system.serviceModel>
      <services>
        <service name="VM1.MyService" behaviorConfiguration="mybehavior">
          <endpoint address="soap” binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="VM1.IService" bindingConfiguration="httpbinding1"></endpoint>
          <endpoint address="soap” binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="VM1.IService" bindingConfiguration="httpsbinding1"></endpoint>
          <endpoint address="rest” binding="webHttpBinding" contract="VM1.IService" behaviorConfiguration="rest" bindingConfiguration="httpbinding2"></endpoint>
          <endpoint address="rest” binding="webHttpBinding" contract="VM1.IService" behaviorConfiguration="rest" bindingConfiguration="httpsbinding2"></endpoint>
          <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" ></endpoint>
        </service>
      </services>
      <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
          <binding name="httpbinding1">
            <security mode="None"></security>
          </binding>
          <binding name="httpsbinding1">
            <security mode="Transport">
              <transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>
            </security>
          </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
        <webHttpBinding>
          <binding name="httpbinding2">
            <security mode="None">
            </security>
          </binding>
          <binding name="httpsbinding2">
            <security mode="Transport">
              <transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>
            </security>
          </binding>
        </webHttpBinding>
      </bindings>
      <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
          <behavior name="mybehavior">
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
          <behavior name="rest">
            <webHttp />
          </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
      </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

Please don’t forget the specify the Http and Https base address in IIS site binding module provided that we host the service in IIS.
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

I've tried to make my config as similar to your as possible but it's still giving me a 404 for SOAP calls over HTTPS.

Are you able to see any issues with my config? I've updated my question with the updated config. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, there’s something wrong with the configuration about the endpoints base address, updated.

Comment: Thanks but same issue sadly

Comment: Which way you use to call the service when sending soap quest? 404 indicates the service address might be wrong or there is something wrong with hosted service.

Comment: I'm using an app called Postman to send the soap calls. It's working fine on http so I don't think the soap call is an issue. Maybe the call is ending up going to another site that is also using https on the server. All of the sites are using the same IP, but different certs by utilising SNI. The server is 2012 and my dev pc Win 10 so I don't think SNI support is the issue.

Comment: I would like to know that if the configuration file could generate the https endpoints based on WsHttpBinding properly when calling the service by adding service reference on the client side, then we could generate the client by utilizing the client proxy construction method (use the https binding endpoint) to call the service.

Comment: From my standpoint, the above method is a standard SOAP request by using the client proxy class to call the service, otherwise, we might add a complex XML file as a request body when sending the SOAP request by using POSTMAN.

Comment: When adding the service reference to the client project is VS, it added the endpoint with http instead of https, even though I added the service url with https and could see/browse the operations in VS when adding it. It then adds an App_WebReferences folder in the root of the site containing some xml files but I get an error saying 'Reference.svcmap: Inheritance security rules violated...' if I try and browse the site. If I remove this folder and call the service over http it works but not via https :(

Comment: DotnetFramework2.0 doesn’t work well with WCF. In the old version project, it only supports web reference instead of the service reference. You could check whether the service available over https by Adding Service Reference in the newer project, such as Dotnetframework 4.5

Comment: Hi Abraham both the server and client projects are .Net 4.7.1

Comment: In order to test the service, we could generate the client proxy class in a new console application. Then we check if the configuration file generates the https endpoint.
Besides, the service name property should use assembly. Interface form, as well as contract property.
name=”VM1.MyService”
contract="VM1.IService"

Comment: Hi I tried this and it generated the endpoint with http instead of https

Comment: Have you modified the above service name and contact name?